# TKInter buttons change or destroy

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue with accessing to Tkinter button objects.
My idea that 2nd button is disabled if first button wasn't pressed.

[image: root]

If 1st button is pressed TopLevel window pops up with input fields.
[image: toplevel]

When 3rd button is pressed works my function.And I'd like to change text of 4th button and destroy 3rd button.
I can't do that from my function

```
 self.win = tk.Toplevel()
    self.win.geometry('350x200')
    self.win.transient(root)
    self.win.grab_set()

 self.btn_cancel = tk.Button(master=self.win, text='Отмена', 
   command=self.win.destroy).grid(row=8, column=1)
 self.btn_conn = tk.Button(master=self.win, text='Проверить', 
   command=self.entry_db_check).grid(row=8, column=0)
 def entry_db_check(self):
 <my code is here>
```

After all manipulation 2nd button must be active.
I saw that it should work so

```
 self.btn_cancel.destroy()
 self.btn_conn['text']='OK'
```

Should I switch to frames instead of TopLevel window to make it work?

Comment: It would be _much_ better if you include error message.

Comment: Just a guess: Since you are trying to access a button which uses `grid` in same line, you are probably getting `NoneType` error. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get

Comment: @Lafexlos, yep. I solved my issue with that answer and didn't pay attention when created these buttons. Thank you.